# javascript is connected but somehow the innerhtml doesnt update

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

I have a simple html that I need to update certain area as text in div. The javascript file is working and the alret function is working but the inner html doesnt work. Note, Im not sure if I need to include the onload function but I was trying without it based on the my research i think it is a must. any suggestion to fix it and advice for best practice and improve the code is appreciated

HTML file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="compjavascript.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">

<div id="sec" onload="fechData();">
 <div class="center"> 
         <div class="column middle"> <p id="text"></p>
             <a href="url" id="link"></a>
         </div>

         <div class="column side">
             <img class="image" id="image" src="download.jpg" >
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

JavaScript File:

```
alert("javascript");

function fechData() {
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "My First JavaScript";
document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = " ";
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = " ";
}
```

Comment: Don't put an `onload` inline handler on a `<div>` (or use inline handlers at all, preferably) - wait for `DOMContentLoaded` instead. Listen for `load` events on *resources*, like `<script>` tags

Comment: You can also just give the `<script>` the `defer` attribute, and have it call `fechData` immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onload` event can only be used on the `body`

```js
function fechData() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "My First JavaScript";
  document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = " ";
  document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = " ";
}
```

```html
<body onload="fechData();">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div id="sec">
      <div class="center">
        <div class="column middle">
          <p id="text"></p>
          <a href="url" id="link"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="column side">
          <img class="image" id="image" src="download.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: More than just `<body>` can have the `onload` attribute